# Django rest framework invert serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In Django, I have in models.py models defined like this :

```py
class foo1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class foo2(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   ....
   foo1 = models.ForeignKey(foo1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
class foo3(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   ....
   foo2 = models.ForeignKey(foo2, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
class foo4(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   ....
   foo3 = models.ForeignKey(foo3, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

....
```

and what i'm expecting to get is a json format like this :

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test1",
    "foo2": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test1",
        "foo3": {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "test1",
              "foo3": { 
                 ...   
 }
},
....
]
```

What I have tried so far, and it gives me the opposite result of what I want, here is my serlialize.py :

```py
class NestedFoo1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'

class Nestedfoo2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo1= NestedFoo1Serializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Facility
        fields = '__all__'
```

the resault (is the opposite of what i want):

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test1",
    "foo4": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test1",
        "foo3": {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "test1",
              "foo2": { 
                 ...   
 }
},
....
]
```

and here is my view.py :

```py
class TreeView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = NestedFoo4Serializer
    queryset = foo4.objects.all()
```

want I want is how to invert the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be in your relations, not in your serializers. Foreign keys are one-to-many relations, which for your example models means:

foo2 can have only one foo1 object assigned, but many foo2 objects can have the same foo1 object assigned. Same goes between foo2 and foo3, foo3 and foo4 etc...

If this is what you want, you can have the API structured like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test1",
    "foo2": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test1",
        "foo3": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test1",
            "foo3": [
              ...   
            ],
          },
          {...}
        ]
      },
      {...}
    ]
  },
....
]
```

Simply set a related name on each of the relations (or use a default one, which will be the "slugified" model name where the relation is defined with `_set` added at the end of it):

```
class foo2(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   ....
   foo1 = models.ForeignKey(foo1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="foo2s")
```

And use it in your serializers with that related name and `many=True`:

```
class foo1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo2s = NestedFoo2Serializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = foo1
        fields = '__all__'
```

If you want have the exact API structure as you've proposed in your question, you have to either reverse the relations, so the relation from `foo1` to `foo2` is defined in `foo1`, or use `OneToOneField` instead, which will limit every `foo2` model to have a unique `foo1` model assigned to it.

Comment: Thank you GwynBleidD, your solution did work.